# Counting a particular value of consecutive zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which looks like below. I need to group by id and check dates window that has at least 3 consecutive zeros in the amount field. If that occurs, I would need to flag it and capture the date when the event occurs.

| id | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 20 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-04 | 10 |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | 15 |
| 1 | 2023-01-06 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-07 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-08 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-09 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 | 8 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 25 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 | 32 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-01-04 | 12 |
| 2 | 2023-01-05 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-01-06 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-01-07 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-01-08 | 13 |
| 2 | 2023-01-09 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-01-10 | 12 |

So the dataframe I am looking to create would look like this.

| id | date | amount | threeplus_consecutivedays_zeros_flag | flag_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 20 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-04 | 10 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | 15 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-06 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-07 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2023-01-08 | 0 | 1 | 2023-01-08 |
| 1 | 2023-01-09 | 0 | 1 | 2023-01-08 |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 | 8 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 25 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 | 32 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-04 | 12 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-05 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-06 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-07 | 0 | 1 | 2023-01-07 |
| 2 | 2023-01-08 | 13 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-09 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-10 | 12 | 0 |  |

I tried counting consecutive zeros in an array but don't know how to "groupby" id. I appreciate any help on how to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function:

```
def flag_zeros(gr):
    cz = 0
    for index, row in gr.iterrows():
        if row['amount'] == 0:
            cz += 1
            if cz >= 3:
                gr.at[index, 'three_consecutive_zeros_flag'] = 1
                gr.at[index, 'flag_date'] = row['date']
        else:
            cz = 0
    return gr
```

Then, you can apply the function to the data frame using group by (Note df is your data frame in the below code):

```
result = df.groupby('id').apply(flag_zeros).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified your function to keep the flag_date same for subsequent zeros following 3 zeros.

Comment: Do you know how I can make the 3 days count a variable? I tried the following, but it is not working.

Comment: `def flag_zeros(gr,no_processing_days):
    cz = 0
    for index, row in gr.iterrows():
        if row['amount'] == 0:
            cz += 1
            if zero_count==no_processing_days:
                potential_flag_date = row['date']
            if cz >= no_processing_days:
                gr.at[index, 'three_consecutive_zeros_flag'] = 1
                gr.at[index, 'flag_date'] = no_processing_days
        else:
            cz = 0
    return gr

result = df.groupby('id',group_keys=False).apply(flag_zeros,axis=1,args=(2,)).fillna(0)`

Comment: def flag_zeros(gr, npd):
    cz = 0
    flag_date = None
    for index, row in gr.iterrows():
        if row['amount'] == 0:
            cz += 1
            if cz >= npd:
                if flag_date is None:
                    flag_date = row['date']
                gr.at[index, 'consecutive_zeros_flag'] = 1
                gr.at[index, 'flag_date'] = flag_date
        else:
            cz = 0
            flag_date = None
        if cz < npd:
            gr.at[index, 'flag_date'] = row['date']
    return gr

Comment: Then, you can test as follows:
consecutive_days = 3 
result = flag_zeros(df, consecutive_days)

Comment: Thanks. I think it is missing the group by statement. So it is giving wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with `rolling()`

```
df['date'].where(df['amount'].ne(0).groupby(df['id']).rolling(3,1).sum().droplevel(0).eq(0))
```

two alternative ways with helper series:

```
h = df['amount'].eq(0).groupby(df['id']).transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())

df['date'].where(df.groupby(['id',h]).cumcount().ge(2))
```

or

```
h = df['amount'].ne(0).groupby(df['id']).cumsum()

df['date'].where(df.loc[df['amount'].eq(0)].groupby(['id',h]).cumcount().ge(2))
```

Output:

```
0            NaN
1            NaN
2            NaN
3            NaN
4            NaN
5            NaN
6            NaN
7     2023-01-08
8     2023-01-09
9            NaN
10           NaN
11           NaN
12           NaN
13           NaN
14           NaN
15           NaN
16    2023-01-07
17           NaN
18           NaN
19           NaN
```